# HorizontalScrollView doesn't scroll to left in RTL mode

Tags: android, right-to-left, horizontalscrollview

I have HorizontalScrollView with   `android:supportsRtl="true"` in my application. But instead of scrolling to left, it scrolling to right anyway. How would i fix this?

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@id/audioScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_normal"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/retakeBtn"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/recordBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/border_drawable"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_micro"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_micro"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >
```

I am running for 17 level api, so attributes in xml should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this example all you have to do is to add this line `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to attribute of `HorizontalScrollView`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image]

remember the `views` inside `HorizontalScrollView` will arrange them depending on `ltr` or `rtl`

Comment: @Lester, just copy the above layout inside your activities layout you will know what is missing, i have tested this layout on HTC with API level 19, and it does works

Comment: thanks, it works on android 6.0 but doesn't work on android 4.2, which is 17 level api.Strange

Comment: @Lester, can you post layout where it is not working, i might be able to help you

Comment: please help me ! i have same problem !

Comment: you need to make changes in the manifest file to define RTL,  android:supportsRtl="true"

Comment: @PankajNimgade thank you! but it does not help any way! please take a look at this link and tell me your opinion [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198827)

Comment: @hamidrezabstn, can you tell me more about this in chat, I believe for some views are not supported at RTL, I am not sure let me see your problem, I will do what I can

Comment: @PankajNimgade thanks for your concern! give me chat way!

Comment: @hamidrezabstn, could you ask a question on stackoverflow regarding this issues ?

Comment: @PankajNimgade i've done it before ! [Stack Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171586/tablayout-and-smarttablayout-in-android-with-api-18-17)

Comment: @hamidrezabstn, it does not use layoutDirection attribute.

Comment: @PankajNimgade it does not make a difference ! please run the example and help me with that ! my project deadline is coming! thank you!

Comment: @hamidrezabstn, ok let me give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113976/discussion-between-pankaj-nimgade-and-hamidrezabstn).

Answer (score 3):

use this code and create view upside down

```
final HorizontalScrollView s=(HorizontalScrollView)ll.findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
    s.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            s.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        }
    }, 100L);
```