# NativeScript how change layout direction in scrollView

Tags: nativescript

I have this ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" android:layoutDirection="rtl">
```

I try change direction scrollView , but not work for me.

But exist private function isLayoutRtl  in
[tns-core-modules-widgets](https://github.com/NativeScript/tns-core-modules-widgets/blob/master/android/widgets/src/main/java/org/nativescript/widgets/HorizontalScrollView.java#L233)

```
private boolean isLayoutRtl() {
        return (this.getLayoutDirection() == LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}
```

I can change orientation horizontal ,But not change scroll rtl.
mor information visit [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784046/horizontalscrollview-doesnt-scroll-to-left-in-rtl-mode).

How change directoin RTL scroll in scroll View?

Tanks

Answer (score 2):

The *direction* can be set by the `orientation` property. Is that indeed what you need? https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview.html#orientation

Comment: very tanks.But not resolve problem.I update question. I would change scroll horizontal RTL.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Take a look at this repo: https://github.com/rkhayyat/SyrianForumFrance

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot and didn't find an official solution. But to keep things working, scroll to the end of the `scrollView` after loading it:

```
onScrollViewLoaded(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    let scrollView = this.$refs.scrollView.nativeView;
    scrollView.scrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollView.scrollableWidth, false)
  },1);
},
```

Answer (score -1):

try to add css `transform: scaleX(-1.0)` to scrollview

Comment: Suggestions to try something belong in comments.